# Cannot set my custom NSView as first responder

Tags: objective-c

I've created a simple subclass of NSView, but calling `becomeFirstResponder` seems to have no effect - the framework doesn't even call my `acceptsFirstResponder` method.

However, if I click with my mouse on my view it seems to becomes the first responder and I can receive `keyDown` events.

Here is my NSView subclass:

```
@interface MyView : NSView
@end

@implementation MyView
- (void) keyDown: (NSEvent*) with {
    NSLog(@"keyDown");
}

- (BOOL)acceptsFirstResponder {
    NSLog(@"acceptsFirstResponder");
    return YES;
}

- (BOOL)canBecomeKeyView {
    NSLog(@"canBecomeKeyView");
    return YES;
}

@end
```

And here is how I'm setting it up in my `AppDelegate`:

```
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification {

      NSRect frameRect = NSMakeRect(0,0,100,100);
      MyView *myView = [[MyView alloc] initWithFrame:frameRect];
      [_window.contentView addSubview:myView];

      [myView becomeFirstResponder];
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you read the documentation of `becomeFirstResponder`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whoops - [the documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsresponder/1526750-becomefirstresponder) says 'Never invoke this method directly'.  So I should call

```
[_window makeFirstResponder:myView];
```

instead of

```
[myView becomeFirstResponder];
```

Thanks to Willeke for the hint.